# Environ Function in XPages

Tags: xpages

I am looking for function in SSJS in XPages instead of "Environ" function.

```
fileName = "tmpExcel.xls"
bantfile =Environ("Temp") & "\" + fileName + ".xls"
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get temporary directory's path on server with SSJS code

```
var tmpPath = java.lang.System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case.

For client side enviro, use [cookies](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cookie-management.html).

For server side enviro, go for [property](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/UsingPropertiesOnAnXPage.htm) files.

Be aware - do not use profile documents. They are cached and it makes problems in multithreaded HTTP context.